# domain of algebraic function

Tags: real-analysis

In Wiki the definition of algebraic function is as following:

An algebraic function in degree $n$ is a function satisfy

$$ a_n(x)y^n + \cdots + a_{1}y + a_0 = 0.$$

My puzzle is that is there a restriction about what domain of an algebraic function should be? Since,we know that

$$ \dfrac 1x ,\ \sqrt{1-x^2},\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^3}} $$

etc.. Are all algebraic function, but with different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a function is algebraic is independent of its domain. There are algebraic functions whose domain is the whole space, i.e. $y=x$, and there are also algebraic functions with domain restrictions, i.e. $y=\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$ or $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x\in[-1,1]$.